# Where are the static files located in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

If we create app engine with `app.yaml` and instructions:

```
- url: /static/(.*\.(css))
  static_files: sheet/\1
  upload: sheet/(.*\.(css))

- url: /static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))$
  static_files: img/\1
  upload: img/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

etc.
My questions are:

1. Where are these files uploaded? Can't find static folder with files
   in, data store or blob or admin, but engine is running and all files
   are accessible from URL.
2. How to delete some files in static folder?
3. How to delete all folders and start fresh?
4. If we update to a new version (say 1.1) then what happens to the old
   version? Is it available or removed?
5. Does creating an app engine as same version overwrite files?

This app engine is a big MYSTERY even PYTHON is an animal rarely found these days. Thanks.

Comment: There is no big "MYSTERY" with app engine.  Its all covered in the documentation.  I suggest you read that first and then come back with questions that are not covered in the docs.  For instance on static files  topic https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers  Oh and dont just skim the docs have a good read.  Comments like "PYTHON is an animal rarely found these days" are way off the mark, and don't encourage engagement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please find my answers inline :

> 1. Where are these files uploaded?

**ANS :** These files are uploaded and kept by google at different location which is not accessible directly to you or your python script without using special directives in the app.yaml.

On the laptop/PC from where you upload your app, it would be in your app source directory but once uploaded, GAE stores it in a different way.

Such files, when mentioned in app.yam ( like you have done ), do not need any handlers ( python subroutines to open and serve them ). GAE has built in handlers to serve them. As you mentioned, you can access them in the same way as way as if they actually resided inside your app source directory.

> 2. Can't find static folder with files in, data store or blob or admin,
>      but engine is running and all files are accessible from URL. How to
>      delete some files in static folder?

**ANS :** First part of this question is answered in Q1's answer.

To delete any of these files or directories, simply delete them ( or move them outside ) your app source directory on your laptop/PC. Then "Deploy" the app once for the changes to reflect in production app ( web ).

> 3. How to delete all folders and start fresh?

**ANS :** Please see Q2 answer.

> 4. If we update to a new version (say 1.1) then what happens to the old
>      version? Is it available or removed?

**ANS :** If I understand it right, you mean to update your app's version in app.yaml file.

Those files remain intact irrespective of any code changes ( which you might call version upgrades of you app ). They would still be available and accessible in the same way.

> 5. Does creating an app engine as same version overwrite files?

**ANS :** I believe you mean : "If I create a different source directory for this app from scratch. Add the code files but do not add the static files ( or directories ) and then "Deploy". Does my static files from the earlier deployment remain ? "

The answer is "no". This is because the GAE does not know if you created another directory from scratch or you deleted and made all changes to the existing one. And it does not matter for GAE or your app. As soon as you deploy the same app id from another source directory, for the same version of app, the code and static files of that source directory is all you have in the production app ( web ).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more clarification is needed regarding question 2; for eg my app.yaml is :

application: app-id

version: 1

runtime: python27

api_version: 1

threadsafe: yes

default_expiration: "7d"

- url: /video/(.*.mp4)

  static_files: video/\1

  mime_type: video/mp4

  upload: video/(.*.mp4)

and directory video contains a file best.mp4, deployed and accessible via app-id.appspot.com/video/best.mp4, hence to remove:

I need to remove video directory (with best.mp4) and deploy removing

- url: /video/(.*.mp4)

  static_files: video/\1

  mime_type: video/mp4

  upload: video/(.*.mp4)

declarations from my app.yaml file

or

to add another mp4 file

I need to rename this new mp4 file as best.mp4 and deploy the app again??

---

**CURRENT APP.YAML**

application: app-id

version: 1

runtime: python27

api_version: 1

threadsafe: yes

default_expiration: "7d"

handlers:

- url: /static/(..html)

  static_files: static/\1

  upload: static/(..html)
- url: /static/(..(css))

  static_files: static/\1

  upload: static/(..(css))
- url: /static/(..(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))$

  static_files: static/\1

  upload: static/(..(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
- url: /static/(..(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))$

  static_files: static/\1

  upload: static/(..(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
- url: /static/(..mp4)

  static_files: static/\1

  mime_type: static/mp4

  upload: static/(..mp4)
- url: .* script: main.app

libraries:

- name: webapp2

  version: "2.5.2"

---

**PREVIOUS APP.YAML (NOT SURE)**

application: app-id

version: 1

runtime: python27

api_version: 1

threadsafe: yes

default_expiration: "7d"

handlers:

- url: /static/(..html)

  static_files: static/\1

  upload: static/(..html)
- url: /static/(..(css))

  static_files: static/\1

  upload: static/(..(css))
- url: /static/(..(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))$

  static_files: static/\1

  upload: static/(..(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
- url: /static/(..(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))$

  static_files: static/\1

  upload: static/(..(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
- url: /(..mp4)        **(THIS CAUSED FILE TO APPEAR ON ROOT)***

  static_files: /\1

  mime_type: /mp4

  upload: /(..mp4)
- url: .* script: main.app

libraries:

- name: webapp2

  version: "2.5.2"

Comment: If you intend to delete a `mp4` file from your app, simply remove that `.mp4` file from your `video` directory ( inside app source directory on your laptop/PC ) and deploy your app. If you want to add several `.mp4` files in you app, put all of them inside the `video` directory ( inside app source directory on your laptop/PC ) and deploy your app. The `*.mp4`, in `app.yaml`, makes sure all the `.mp4` files get uploaded and served from your app.

Comment: If you have a lot of `.mp4` files to serve from your app, it might be a better idea to use [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) or Blobstore to upload the files.

Comment: As a side note, I understand that you are new to this forum, it is recommended to update your existing question with more queries if those queries could not be put in comments.

Comment: Okay, a .mp4 file was deployed (wrongly) at root of url app-id.appspot.com, then i deleted this file from root directory ( inside app source directory on my laptop/PC ) and created new directory video and put all of my new .mp4 files (not the previous file) there, made adjustments in my app.yaml and deployed again. TO MY SURPRISE, all the files in video are accessible but the old .mp4 at root is also accessible.(something I am doing wrong, **may be any of 4 files (present in app-id directory on pc) i.e. app.yaml or index.yaml or main.py or main.pyc needs to be RENAMED**)

Comment: The `.mp4` file at root should not be accessible now. Could you please post the entire `app.yaml` file in your question for more inspection ? That might help someone to point the error.

Comment: Please check **previous app.yaml** I forgot to mention static folder and deployed (after sometime I found my mistake and realized a single .mp4 file was present at root level i.e. app-id.appspot.com/; Later I modified my app.yaml as currrent app,yaml and uploaded different .mp4 files under static folder. (PLEASE NOTE THERE MAY BE some syntax errors as I DONT HAVE THE EXACT COPY but everything was uploaded and worked as i mentioned). Thanks

Comment: your new `app.yaml` appears fine. Are you still able to access the video at root URL ? ( assuming you have deleted the mp4 from app-id source directory root and then deployed your app after that )

Comment: Ok, now I have checked again, its not AVAILABLE at root; I guess it takes some time to changes to reflect ; may be statement **[default_expiration: "7d"]** is causing it.

Comment: Even, when I have recently changed my app version to 2 by changing statement **version: 2** in my current app.yaml and modified files (**but did not rename them**) under static directory; to my surprise, after testing 2.app-id.appspot.com (everything was fine) , I made it default version from dashboard, now I have both old files (same name at app-id.appspot.com and (**modified files with same name**) at 2.app-id.appspot.com??